# Do not render image preview in monaco comments

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

The comments in monaco are markdown.
If I open the monaco [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) and paste the following code:

```
/**
 * Just a function
 * [![IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE](https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png)](https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png)
 */
function displayimage () {
 
}
```

When I hover over the function displayimage() it renders the image (../1.png).
The markdown is converted to html in monaco which shows the image on hover.

I'm trying to use Monaco in my custom editor but it seems that this could be possible security risk. If someone even accidentally hovers over the function, their IP could be exposed to the link given.

What I tried:

I tried to disable the markdown render itself using something like:

```
  monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider('typescript', {
      provideHover:
          (model: monaco.editor.ITextModel, position: monaco.Position,
           token: monaco.CancellationToken) => null
    });
```

but that didn't work.

Questions:

1. Is my understanding that it's a security risk correct?
2. Irrespective of the previous question, What would be the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: I believe that's not really a security issue. The image is shown only if the user himself writes a comment like that. So he's deciding to take the risk.

It would be more serious if someone else but the user/code writer could add such links into these comments.